# Do Webform Contributions allow for using Grid Widget?

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, webform-civicrm, contributions

This is a simple yes/no question, but to explain:

Since price-sets aren't integrated into webform, I'd like to recreate a price-set directly in the webform. The civicrm webform integration help (screenshot below) seems to indicate that this is possible, as does [this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/2241843) on the integration support request queue. 
[image: contribution amount help]

However, I don't see the grid widget as an option when I look for it, and am wondering whether I should go looking for the issue in my setup or whether grid is simply unsupported by the current integration module. (screenshot below)

[image]

I'm using Drupal 7, CiviCRM 4.6.18, Webform 4.12 and Webform CiviCRM Integration 4.14. Does anyone know if there is a setting I'm missing?

Comment: I looked for it but not seeing grid either - would like to know the answer too!

Comment: I've pinged Coleman - he should be able to tell us!

Comment: Nice to see evidence that people (or at least one person) clicks on the (?) icons and actually reads the help!

Comment: @Coleman I use that all the time, please keep it going!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, that was a bug in the webform_civicrm module. I've just [pushed up a fix](https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/commit/c32a0462d7af21d58bc04a88344f53a928653f29), which will be part of 7.x-4.16. Or you can grab the latest -dev release from [drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) now.

Update: 4.16 has been released. Enjoy.

Comment: Ah... ok that explains things. Thank you!

Comment: I'm apparently not allowed to award the bounty for 6 more hours, but it's coming your way eventually.

Comment: anyone able to show me a working example of grid for a replacement of line items?